# Changing browser windows with window.location in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a web site that is in two languages, English and French. now i do not know java-script, I created a code for showing different pictures using javascript depending on which language u want to use.

So if you are on the www.my-site.com/en/ you will see En_pic_ pictures same goes for the opposite.

```
/*These are the Popup images for the English and French portal */

var url1 = 'http://www.my-site.com/fr/';
var url2 = 'http://www.my-site.com/en/';
MagnifImage.setup(
if (window.location = 'url2'){  
"En_pic_1", "/images/1.png","",
"En_pic_2", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/2.png",  "",
"En_pic_3", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/3.png", "",
"En_pic_4", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/4.png", "",
}else{
"Fr_pic_1", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/1_fr.png", "",
"Fr_pic_2", "/images/mon-compte.png","",
"Fr_pic_3", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/3_fr.png","",
"Fr_pic_4", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/4_fr.png",""
}
);
```

Everything works but if I am on the other language page I get an alert box saying there is no Fr_pic_1 or En_pic_1.(depending on the current page I am in) The code I found to accomplish this as follows:

```
if( !(objRef.trigElem=document.getElementById( idParts[0] )) )
 alert("There is no element with the ID:'"+idParts[0]+"'\n\nCase must match exactly\n\nElements must be located ABOVE the script initialisation.");
else
{
 if(objRef.trigElem.parentNode && objRef.trigElem.parentNode.tagName=='A')
  objRef.trigElem=objRef.trigElem.parentNode;

 objRef.classId=idParts[1] || "MagnifImage" ;
 objRef.imgObj=new Image();

 objRef.imgObj.imgIndex=i;
 objRef.imgObj.hasLoaded=0;
```

its a code I found at http://scripterlative.com?magnifimage

Please help....

Comment: What's the problem again? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: if I am on the English side I want to see English pictures. But I get an alert. saying There is no element with the ID:Fr_pic_1. So I just want a Js (switcher) to reflect the current page language and use relevant pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix multiple things:

1. You must use `==` or `===` for comparison.  A single `=` is assignment, not comparison.
2. You must compare to the variable name `url2`, not a quoted string `'url2'`.
3. You must fix the way you pass the alternate parameters to your function `MagnifImage.setup()`.
4. I switched to using `window.location.href` because window.location is an object and I find it better to use the actual attribute of that object you want rather than rely on an implicit conversion.

Change your code to this:

```
/*These are the Popup images for the English and French portal */

var url1 = 'http://www.my-site.com/fr/';
var url2 = 'http://www.my-site.com/en/';
if (window.location.href == url2) {  
    MagnifImage.setup("En_pic_1", "/images/1.png","",
        "En_pic_2", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/2.png",  "",
        "En_pic_3", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/3.png", "",
        "En_pic_4", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/4.png", "");
} else {
    MagnifImage.setup("Fr_pic_1", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/1_fr.png", "",
        "Fr_pic_2", "/images/mon-compte.png","",
        "Fr_pic_3", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/3_fr.png","",
        "Fr_pic_4", "/img/content/tracking_instructions/4_fr.png","");
}
```

Your code was likely causing many errors and thus not executing at all.  You should learn how to look for javascript errors.  Every browser has an error console that will show you javascript parsing or executing errors.  Many browsers now have a built-in debugger than has a console in it that will also show you such information and allow you to see the exact source line causing the error.  I use Chrome which has a built-in debugger which will do this.  Firefox has a free add-on called Firebug that will do this.

Comment: After looking up the documentation for MagnifImage.setup, I changed the way that function is called and offered a new code fix in my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 +1 for your time and effort. Thank you so much. I know I took a long time to reply. But this project was put on hold. now I came back to it.. Your code worked !!